# python how are sets items arranged (Ordered)

Tags: python-3.x

I am Confused Of how Sets Items are Arranged Cause for Example :

```
s1 = {2,1,3,6}

print(s1)       ===> {1,2,3,6}

s1 = {2,1,30,6}

print(s1)       ===> {1,2,6,60}

s1 = {2,1,300,6}

print(s1)       ===> {1,2,300,6}

s1 = {2,1,3,6}

print(s1)       ===> {3000,1,2,6}
```

But For Alphapetic Characters It Seems Random for Example :

```
s1 = {'A','B','C','D'}

first Run ====> {'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'}

Second Run ===> {'B', 'A', 'C', 'D'}

Third Run ====> {'C', 'B', 'A', 'D'}
```

it Keeps Changing so It Is Kinda Random But For Numbers It is Constant

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help]. You can also read about [ask] a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to say:

1. There is an inconsistency on your fourth line - the definition of `s1` should be `s1 = {2,1,3000,6}` - to match with your console output;
2. I don't know what you mean by 'runs' but, when opening an instance of the Python console (version 3.4.3 for me), when I type in `s1 = {2,1,6,3}` then `print(s1)`, the console outputs `{1, 2, 3, 6}`; however, when I type `s1 = {'1','2','3','6'}` then `print(s1)`, the console outputs `{'2', '4', '3', '1'}` so I can say, from observation, that this random ordering of objects seems to affect strings but not integers - it seems these are ordered correctly automatically. The second output also occurs with other object types (typing in `s2 = {'a','b','c','d'}` then `print(s2)` gave me `{'c', 'b', 'd', 'a'}`);
3. When doing the exact same inputs as above after closing and reopening the Python console, the following output appeared for me: `{1, 2, 3, 6}`, `{'3', '2', '1', '4'}`, `{'b', 'c', 'd', 'a'}`. So it seems to change every time you open a new Python console. I know that sets are unordered collections of unique objects (the same object can't be repeated twice in the same set - it will be removed automatically when outputted), but I don't know the reason behind that.

That's all I have to say about your question - if you want to find out more, I would suggest a google search on `set ordering in python 3` or any other search to help you find more information.

**Edit**

According to the book Learning Python 5th Edition, the definition of a set is:

> an unordered collection of unique and immutable objects that supports operations corresponding to **mathematical set theory**.

It may be that the creators of Python wanted sets to order mathematical values to make the application of sets in mathematical areas that little bit easier.